# CSS file does not get loaded when 2nd CSS file by same name exists in different directory

Tags: asp.net, css

CSS file does not get loaded when 2nd CSS file by same name exists in different directory.
Only first one loaded.
Can anyone help me?

```
link href="/Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"//fisst

link href="/Content/css/uniform.css" rel="stylesheet"

link href="/Content/font/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"

link href="/Content/Tenant/BIP/Ocean/style.css" rel="stylesheet"//second>
```

Comment: We're not mind readers, include your code if you expect anyone to help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or not, but you don't appear to have 2 stylesheets by the same name...

Comment: style.css 1 line and last line

Comment: first line reads `styles.css` while last line only reads `style.css`. Is this the exact code? I'm only asking because if you copy and pasted this, then the issue is not the naming convention of your stylesheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you named the second stylesheet something else than the first. The first is styles.css and the second is style.css

Comment: Good eye, but this is probably best suited as a comment rather than an answer. EDIT - I stand corrected lol